# Scrolling UL list within the division

Tags: html, css

I have created a UL list with a heading .But when I scroll heading is covered up as shown in the image

[image]

```css
.project-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;
}

.file-source {
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

ul.menu {
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

ul.menu li.selected {
  background-color: #23ac61;
}

ul.menu li.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 file-source">
  <div>
    <h4 class="project-header">Projects</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="projects">
    <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me with creating this

Comment: Please show us the CSS you are using (or if you are using a framework let us know what it is), so we can see what is happening and be able to help.

Comment: how do you want the heading to look like - you have told how do want the final results to be

Comment: heading should be in the beginning of container with fixed position and scrolling of list should not cover the heading

Comment: z-index doesn't help?

Comment: tried with z-index

Comment: use `width: 100%` for `.project-header`

Comment: Thank you..z-index:1 along with width solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to position information.If you make the position of the project-header object static, maybe the problem is solved.

You can try this.

```
.project-header {
  position:static;
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```css
.project-header {
  position:static;
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;
}

.file-source {
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

ul.menu {
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

ul.menu li.selected {
  background-color: #23ac61;
}

ul.menu li.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 file-source">
  <div>
    <h4 class="project-header">Projects</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="projects">
    <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
      <li>sales 1</li>
     <li>Sales 2</li>
     <li>sales 3</li>
      <li>sales 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```